# Rainbow hat android things minsdk=24 error

Tags: android, android-things

Im creating a test application with blinking led on Raspberry pi 3 B with the use of android things and rainbow hat by pimoroni but when i tried it, it says

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 24 cannot be smaller than version 27 declared in library [com.google.android.things.contrib:driver-rainbowhat:1.0] C:\Users\LENOVO-PC\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\driver-rainbowhat-1.0.aar\d5f46e61011d32f9fa318c0bb291f09a\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 24
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 24,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 27,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.rainbowhat" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

my app gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lenovo_pc.anythingtesting"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.so'], dir: 'libs')
    //   implementation 'com.google.android.things.contrib:driver-apa102:0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.things.contrib:driver-rainbowhat:1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
       compileOnly 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:1.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and my androidmanifest.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.lenovo_pc.anythingtesting">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.USE_PERIPHERAL_IO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!--   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />  -->



      <application

          android:extractNativeLibs="false"


          android:label="@string/app_name">
          <uses-library android:required="false" android:name="com.google.android.things"/>
          <!--               android:required="false"
                        tools:replace="android:required"  -->


                    <activity android:name=".innovatrics.MainActivity">
                        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="blink" />
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                        </intent-filter>
                        <!--
                                    <intent-filter>
                                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.IOT_LAUNCHER" />
                                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                                    </intent-filter>
                                    -->
                    </activity>
                </application>


            </manifest>
```

Im running the application in Raspberry pi 3 B and I've watched different tutorials that minsdkversion is okay with 24. So im not sure what's wrong with my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at an outdated tutorial. The minSdk was raised from [24 to 26](https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/commit/017bb9208a876e7b90621b043626ada53a0cba18#diff-c197962302397baf3a4cc36463dce5ea) on november 29 2017 and from [26 to 27](https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/commit/759f8433e39c8327f8ce72e11710f02fe8764f10#diff-c197962302397baf3a4cc36463dce5ea) on march 22 2018.

You must use minSdk 27+ now.

Comment: does that mean i cannot use the raspberry pi 3 B with android things now?

Comment: it means that your test app must have minSdk of 27 or higher

Comment: but can it still run on rpi3 B?

Comment: The Android Things OS is based on API 27, so it will run fine on the 3B